# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Apache Cordova CTP3 Breaking/Stopping on Javascript lines with no breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am running Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3 installed. After creating a brand new Apache Cordova project, and then debugging it, it breaks/pauses/stops on seemingly random lines of javascript files where there are no breakpoints.  Meaning, it stops on lines as if there was a breakpoint there, but there really isn't.  I'm using RIPPLE debugging only. I don't use a device or emulator AT ALL.

At one point, I had installed Visual Studio 2015 CTP5, and an associated update to the Android Emulator that was recommended.  I since have uninstalled them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that appeared since a recent update to Chrome, and it is being worked on. You can run your app on Ripple by hitting F5 through the debugger breaks (hardly satisfactory), or Ctrl+F5 to start your app without debugging in Ripple. To debug, the better option is to run on on an emulator. The VS Emulator for Android on VS 2015 Preview has been working well for me. In VS 2013, GenyMotion is probably the best option for Android.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be true!  I really thought the issue was with Visual Studio and/or Tools for Apache Cordova.  But apparently, the issue revolves around Chrome 40? Cause it seems like Chrome 39 works just fine.  I'm hoping updates to Chrome 40+ will have fixes/patches to resolve this issue with Ripple.

Comment: Has this been fixed? I am having the same issue with Chrome 43

Answer (score 0):

I have having the same problem as discussed here but noone seems able to help
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10b9a01c-4afa-443e-83d5-fa4cd92493c0/visual-studio-cordova-templateangularjstodo-example-project-debug-issue?forum=vsdebug&prof=required

Comment: Add link in comment section. Or post the link content as answer and add the link as reference

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing: Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Cordova Tools.
Then click on the button 'Clear Cordova Cache'. Give it a few minutes..

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I noticed, is that I might have had CTP3.0 vs CTP3.1. Be sure to take a real close look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3014133?wa=wsignin1.0