# Which order should you add WinJS to Cordova projects?

Tags: cordova, winjs, visual-studio-cordova

**TLDR: WinJS on Cordova is confusing. Scroll to the bottom for the questions.**

I’m trying to work on a sample using WinJS inside of Cordova. I’ve done a bunch of Cordova projects before, so I’m familiar with that, and the same with WinJS. But together, they throw some issues.

Microsoft has a few Cordova samples already:

- AngularJS sample
- WinJS sample (TypeScript sample)
- Backbone sample
- WinJS stocks sample

I’m trying to do WinJS, but *without* Typescript. The idea behind this is to either grab the attention of Cordova developers or WinJS developers, and get them looking at these tools. Once we throw TypeScript in the mix, it’s a different animal, and one more thing for them to learn.

This is the best sample and documentation I’ve seen so far: Visual Studio Magazine – Write Cross Platform Cordova apps in Visual Studio w/ Cordova. He references Cordova BEFORE WinJS:

```
    <script src="scripts/frameworks/base.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/frameworks/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/frameworks/winjs.js"></script>
```

In that Typescript sample, the references are loaded like this:

```
    <script src="./scripts/frameworks/base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/frameworks/ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Cordova reference (must be added AFTER base.js reference) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
```

In the stocks sample, it is loaded as such:

```
    <script src="winjs/js/WinJS.js"></script>
      ………..
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Notice: one uses base & ui, while the other uses WinJS. Both come BEFORE Cordova. I don’t think you need to, though. I illustrate that below.

**Test 1:**

- Created a new Cordova app in Visual Studio 2013
- Installed WinJS from NPM (Install-Package WinJS)
- Added my references:
- Build the app, deploying for iOS in Ripple
- VS always stops on line 1938 of cordova.js (final line in the script)
  })();
- Hit continue, and it stops on line 73634 of WinjS.js (final line)
  }(this));
- Hit continue, and it stops on the final line of index.js 
  })();
- Hit continue one last time, and it loads in Ripple, and behaves like it should

**Test 2:**

```
    <script src="cordova.js">                   </script>
    <script src="/WinJS/js/base.min.js">        </script> 
    <script src="/WinJS/js/ui.min.js">          </script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js">             </script>
```

I have the same issue!

- Build the app, deploying for iOS in Ripple
- VS always stops on line 1938 of cordova.js (final line in the script)
  })();

  - Hit continue, and it stops on line 11 of base.min.js (final line)
  - Hit continue, and it stops on line 11 of ui.min.js (final line)
  - Hit continue, and it stops on the final line of index.js 
    })();
  - Hit continue one last time, and it loads in Ripple, and behaves like it should

**Test 3:**

```
<script src="/WinJS/js/base.min.js">        </script>
<script src="/WinJS/js/ui.min.js">          </script>
<script src="cordova.js">                   </script>   
<script src="scripts/index.js">             </script>
```

- Build the app, deploying for iOS in Ripple
- Hit continue, and it stops on line 11 of base.min.js (final line)
- Hit continue, and it stops on line 11 of ui.min.js (final line)
- Hit continue, and it stops on line 1938 of cordova.js (final line in the script)
  })();
- Hit continue, and it stops on the final line of index.js 
  })();
- Hit continue one last time, and it loads in Ripple, and behaves like it should

So I’ve got a few questions:

1. When is base and UI necessary?
2. When is just WinJS necessary?
3. Why does it keep stopping on those lines? It’s a yellow arrow, so
   I’m assuming it’s a warning, but it’s not clear about what it’s
   telling me.

**NOTE:**  If you use WinJS.js, it has to be referenced AFTER Cordova.js
If you use base & UI, you can do it before OR after Cordova.js
Weird.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you target one of the emulators? If this issue is limited to Ripple, you are encountering a recent Ripple bug. See this post: [Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Apache Cordova CTP3 Breaking/Stopping on Javascript lines with no breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376223/visual-studio-2013-update-4-and-apache-cordova-ctp3-breaking-stopping-on-javascr). RE: WinJS, I believe you can use either winjs or base/ui, but to use both is redundant. The difference in required loading order that you mention is very strange, however.